# If X, Z are independent, Y, Z are independent, then are XY and Z independent?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-probability, independence

If $X, Z$ are independent, $Y, Z$ are independent, then are $XY,Z$ independent?

How about:

If $X,Y,Z$ are mutually independent, then are $XY, Z$ independent?

If none of the above is true, is there any such lemma that derives the independence from that of $X,Z$ and $Y,Z$?

Please show work or refer to a link, thank you!

Comment: Pairwise independent variables may not be mutually independent. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence#Example for an example

Comment: If $(X_\alpha)$ and $(Y_\beta)$ are independent families of random variables, then any measurable function of these families will yield independent random variables; that is, if $X = f((X_\alpha)_\alpha)$ and $Y = g((Y_\beta)_\beta),$ then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 3):

For your first question, no: let $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ be two i.i.d. random variables taking the values $1$ and $-1$ with probability $1/2$. Let $X=\epsilon_1$, $Y=\epsilon_2$ and $Z=\epsilon_1\epsilon_2$.

For your second question, it is a consequence of the definition of mutual independence.

Comment: Thank @Davide, I see it! But it's a bit counterintuitive that $X, XY$ (in fact in this case $XY=X^2$) can be independent...